# Array formula with IF not populating column in Google sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas

I cannot seem to make my array formula populate downwards from the first referenced row for some reason.

Background: I have 15 formulas in an active document that I would like the to autopopulate with the formulas when I create new rows.

The way to do this seems to be ArrayFormula and changing the references from say O2 to O2:O to make it populate the sheet.

I am making some basic error here and I need some assistance :)

Link to test sheet *some headers are in Swedish (sorry) :)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P7M73-ITRG3LNA5O7yR0grj40d9tFF8Ve6ed6hQkiyc/edit?usp=sharing

My testing;  this is in the example sheet in G1

Orig formula which works fine dragging into new rows

```
=IF(AND(O2=""),"",IFERROR(MAX(($V2)/$X2,0)))
```

The formula checks for empty cells and if not it will calculate a percentage based on other formulas.

Array with original formula + header row

```
={"Klar"; ArrayFormula(IF(AND(O2=""),"",IFERROR(MAX((V2)/X2,0))))}
```

This results in O2 populating as expected

With somehow incorrect references which I hoped would populate the whole column

```
={"Klar"; ArrayFormula(IF(AND(O2:O=""),"",IFERROR(MAX((V2:V)/X2:X,0))))}
```

I expect the formula to currently populate O2-> O6 and to go into new rows with data when they appear.

I also expect to be able to do arrays for all 15 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `MAP()` function. I have made this formula based on your provided formula ***=IF(AND(O2=""),"",IFERROR(MAX(($V2)/$X2,0)))***.

```
=MAP(O2:O,V2:V,X2:X,LAMBDA(x,y,z,IF(x="","",MAX(y/z,0))))
```

[image]

Comment: This works wonders,

I added the header to it  ={"Klar";MAP(O2:O,V2:V,X2:X,LAMBDA(x,y,z,IF(x="","",MAX(y/z,0))))}.

When it comes to my other formulas, do you think I should remake them into map's too?

also, do you know the error I made?

Comment: @Celebrin Glad to know! If it works, then please consider accepting the answer (tick mark it) to treat the question as solved.

Comment: Sure thing, :) now I just haveto find out how to make MAP work for me properly.